# 'Undefined reference to "WinMain@16" ' while setting up SDL2 with CMake

Tags: cmake, sdl-2, clion

So I want to learn how to use CMake (specifically in CLion), and right now I'm trying to set up SDL2 with it. I got FindSDL2.cmake in my Modules folder, and this is my code:

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(CLion_Tests)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(SDL2_PATH "C:/Users/Lerchi/Downloads/SDL/SDL2main/64")
find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR})

add_executable(CLion_Tests main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(CLion_Tests ${SDL2_LIBRARY})
```

and main.cpp is just this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char* args[]) {
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The error I'm getting is

```
CMakeFiles\CLion_Tests.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):main.cpp:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CLion_Tests.exe] Error 1
CMakeFiles\CLion_Tests.dir\build.make:87: recipe for target 'CLion_Tests.exe' failed
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/CLion_Tests.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:71: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/CLion_Tests.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make.exe: *** [all] Error 2
Makefile:82: recipe for target 'all' failed
```

Comment: The first error you get is `undefined reference to \`SDL_Init'`, so it is better to concentrate on it. But according to the second error message, you build the project for 32-bit MinGW target. I don't know which target supports your SDL2 binaries, but suffix `64` in the path `C:/Users/Lerchi/Downloads/SDL/SDL2main/64` suggests, that it is 64-bit target, which is definitely not compatible with 32-bit MinGW one. You need to download SDL2 binaries for the same target, for which you build the project.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I redownloaded the 32bit version, and it still gives me the exact same error.

Comment: So, have you downloaded the library binaries for MinGW or for, e.g., Visual Studio?